# Question on unicode translation

Tags: unicode, utf-8, translation

How does a variable length UTF-8 encoded bytes are decoded/translated to unicode characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each byte with value above `127` (binary `01111111`, `7f` hex) is a part of a multibyte character.

So, if the first bit is 0, done - single byte character.
If not, this is a *continuation byte* - the bits in the byte also determine how many bytes are in this character (technically up to 6-byte characters would be possible, but UTF-8 is only defined for 1-4 byte characters).

For a history and a more detailed explanation, see this article by Our Fearless Leader ;) [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), or [this wikipedia article on  UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF8) (has more technical details on valid/invalid byte combinations)

Answer (score 1):

i think it's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 *is* Unicode, so there is no translation. If you mean "How do I see non-ASCII characters on screen when I'm displaying a Unicode string", you need to ensure you have a Unicode-capable font installed & in use.

My company is using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) font.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is incorrect. UTF-8 is a system for converting characters to bytes and vice versa, which *encodes* Unicode characters (similarly, ASCII *encodes* the Latin alphabet, but it *is not* the alphabet); in a programmer-metaphor, you could say that "UTF-8 implements the Unicode interface". Although UTF-8 is the most known one, there are others - amongst them UTF-7, UTF-16, UTF-32. I recommend the Wikipedia page on Unicode, and the links in my answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: Unicode are _codepoints_ which make up a unicode character from variable length byte encoding which is called _UTF-8_.

Comment: @user4344: That is an oversimplification, which would only be completely correct if there was One Encoding To Rule Them All, UTF-8. Unicode *codepoint* is essentially a number, which represents a character. This number can be encoded in **various encodings**, amongst them UTF-7, UTF-8, etc. Please do read this, the difference between *"is"* and *"represents"* is rather crucial here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Piskvor-the OP is aksing how to translate UTF-8 encoded bytes (I assume a string or stream) to Unicode characters. UTF-8 *is* a Unicode encoding, so "translating to Unicode" is meaningless unless he wants a specfific encoding, like the UTF-16 used internally in Microsoft tools. If the user is looking to present the represented charactes on-screen as I mention, he needs a Unicode capable font.

Answer (score 0):

It is as [@Piskvor describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960406/question-on-unicode-translation/4960583#4960583).

The algorithms for encoding/decoding UTF-8 is described in [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3).

The following table of (32 bit) Unicode code point ranges to byte sequences comes from that document:

```
Char. number range  |        UTF-8 octet sequence
   (hexadecimal)    |              (binary)
--------------------+---------------------------------------------
0000 0000-0000 007F | 0xxxxxxx
0000 0080-0000 07FF | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
0000 0800-0000 FFFF | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
0001 0000-0010 FFFF | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

Comment: Does the byte position depend on endianness of processor?